# Advanced routes in backbone.js with functional grouping

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, routes

Here is an example of my routes structure:

```
routes:{
 "*actions" : "defaultHandler", //some default handler
 //handlers for all pages
 "Page1" : "Page1",
 . . . . . . . . . .
 "PageN" : "PageN",

 //and now I have a module, with it's own pages, and routes for it has similar look:
 "Module/Page01" : "Page01",
 . . . . . . . . . .
 "Module/PageNN" : "PageNN",

 /* and now I have to do some task for all navigations 
    to the Module and I am trying to make this: */

 "Module/*path" : "moduleHandler"

  /* and it's not working, because in this case on navigate, for example
     to the page "Module/Page01" only moduleHandler responding, not Page01 handler */
}
```

Like that. And I need both handlers to respond. Can't find any trick for this in documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this: https://github.com/FLOChip/backbone_router_filter
But, of course, it's only an example and you should implement filtering that would be depend on a route. Feel free to ask if you encounter difficulties.

**Updated**: I've just found this: https://github.com/angelo0000/backbone_filters. If I understand it's exactly what you want.

```
var R = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "page1": "page1",
        "pageN": "pageN",
        "module/page01": "page01",
        "module/pageNN": "pageNN",
        "*actions" : "defaultHandler"
    },

    before: {
        '^module/': 'moduleFilter'
    }
    //...
 });
```

Comment: Nice solution, like Swiss knife. Thanks!

Comment: But I found a few limitations, но пожалуйста :).